# Is there any knapsack-based cryptosystem that has not yet been broken?

Tags: public-key, knapsack

I co-authored and implemented [SRVB](http://srvbblog.wordpress.com/), an asymmetric cryptosystem, only to eventually realize that it is strongly related to Merkel-Hellman cryptosystem, which has been broken. In order to help me investigate the efficacy of this development I took part of, what are the knapsack inspired attempts of asymmetric cryptosystem?

Thank you in advance.

edit:

SRVB is finally [documented in an academic style](https://www.academia.edu/35071647/SRVB_Cryptosystems_four_approaches_for_Knapsack-based_cryptosystems):

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: http://www.iacr.org/archive/tcc2010/59780380/59780380.pdf ​ ​

Comment: If you are interested in getting people to analyze your cryptosystem, you might consider documenting what it is.  I went through the page you gave, and the only thing I could find is the implementation on github.  I assure you; people aren't very interested in poring over your code to reconstruct the algorithm...

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the [Okamoto-Tanaka-Uchiyama](http://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2000/18800147/18800147.pdf) and the [Murakami-Nasako](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/107) knapsack cryptosystem have not been broken, but I'm not an expert in this field and cannot tell whether it received enough attention from experts to be deemed secure. The OTU cryptosystem was analyzed in [this paper](http://www.di.ens.fr/users/stern/data/St113.pdf), and the authors state that they "actually
believe that this system may be secure with an appropriate choice of the
parameters".

In any case, the link you gave seem strange. Why not trying to publish your cryptosystem in a peer-reviewed conference, or recruiting an expert to study its security, rather than offering a "crowdfunded money prize" to anyone that breaks it? It does not look like a good way to make people confident regarding the security of your proposal.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you suppose you could add a little more bibliographic information to the references while this is fresh in your, um, browser cache?  For instance, the Nguyen–Stern paper looks like it's out of one user's (Stern's) home directory at ens.fr.  (But I suppose maybe it's just a tech report at an institution that doesn't have an institutional repository for such things.)

Comment: The Nguyen-Stern paper was published at Asiacrypt 2005, I picked the link from the personal website of Stern because it's the only one I could find which was not behind a paywall. Yasuyuki Murakami has published papers related to the one I linked (I've not verified whether one of them was actually the same as on ePrint) at ISITA 2010, 2012, and 2014.  Finally, the OTU cryptosystem was published at Crypto 2000.